# How to auto mirror a shape in Android XML

Tags: android

I have a custom card like shape as below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="?attr/colorListItemBackground" />

    <corners
        android:bottomLeftRadius="16dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="16dp" />

</shape>
```

My app also supports RTL languages, thus changing to RTL, this shape does not change(Auto Mirror).

What changes can I do to make it an auto mirror?

Notice the rounded corners near the circle.
[LTR_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zo4Kd.png)

The rounded corners still in the same place.
[RTL_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LocRb.png)

Comment: Do you mean you want your layout to follow RTL ? If so you can see the implementation here : https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2013/03/native-rtl-support-in-android-42.html

Comment: My Layout already follows RTL guidelines. All my vector drawables and other views mirrors, but for some reason, this custom view does not.

Comment: I have added images, notice the rounded corners near the circle. I want the same with RTL layout

Comment: Yes got it, see my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have define custom shape inside

```
res/
  drawable 
  drawable-ldltr 
  drawable-ldrtl
```

Now put the mirrored custom shape inside `drawable-ldrtl` and it should work.

Your custom shape xml should be exactly opposite i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="?attr/colorListItemBackground" />

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="16dp"
        android:topRightRadius="16dp" />

</shape>
```

You can alternatively add `android:autoMirrored="true"` to your vector drawable which should auto mirror it. But this requires you to have a vector image as per documentation : https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/VectorDrawable

Hence a shortcut is to wrap your shape around with a vector drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:src="@drawable/your_shape"
        android:autoMirrored="true"/>
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks, that worked, I cannot upvotes as I don't have enough reputations. However, I wanted this as auto mirror, In your mentioned case I have to add all the custom drawabes in the RTL res folder. Also, I have animations, now I had to add another folder in res as anim-ldrtl and add all reverse animations into it. This gets huge when I have multiple views and animations that are custom. Is there any other automatic way, like in vector drawables ?

Comment: Nope, there is no attribute as autoMirrored for shape. It is there in vector parent.